# I want to use macros or template metaprogramming to generate some code for me

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I need to define an enum like

```
    enum class MyEnum { MyEnum1 = 0x0001, MyEnum2 = 0x0002, MyEnum3 = 0x0004, MyEnum4 = 0x0008, MyEnum5 = 0x0010 };
```

So basically these enum values are 1 shifted by the index of enum I want to avoid any typos in case in future some adds a new enum value and I can simply define an array of string for the named enums and generate functions for it and return value based on the index of enum.

this can be broken down to something like this . Say I have an array

```
    constexpr std::array<const char*, 3> arr = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};
    
    //Now at compile time i want to generate functions 
    constexpr int getFoo() { return 0; }
    constexpr int getBar() { return 1; }
    constexpr int getBaz() { return 2; }
```

Basically i want to iterate over array and generate getter functions over the values in array and return the index in array.

Not sure even if its possible but vaguely remember such code being generated using ## in macros

Comment: This is possible using the preprocessor, but the syntax is going to be `FOO((Foo)(Bar)(Baz))` - so, not an array, but a hardcoded list of strings (which can be moved to a `#define`). Can you tell us why you need this?

Comment: tell us about why you need it, about the initial problem this is supposed to solve, rather than only how you want to do it, then we can help you much better. Smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is `constexpr` since c++20

Comment: I need to define an enum like

enum class MyEnum
{
 MyEnum1 = 0x0001,
 MyEnum2 = 0x0002,
 MyEnum3 = 0x0004,
 MyEnum4 = 0x0008,
 MyEnum5 = 0x0010
};
So basically these enum values are 1 shifted by the index of enum
I want to avoid any typos in case in future some adds a new enum value and I can simply define an array of string for the named enums and generate functions for it and return value based on the index of enum

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks but my code is c++14

Comment: I think already in c++14 you can write a `constexpr` find, not sure though.

Comment: "I need to define an enum like enum class ..." you should include this comment in the question

Answer (score 3):

> I need to define an enum like enum class MyEnum { MyEnum1 = 0x0001, MyEnum2 = 0x0002, MyEnum3 = 0x0004, MyEnum4 = 0x0008, MyEnum5 = 0x0010 };

Take a look at [`macro_sequence_for`](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for). This almost exactly matches the very first example in the readme.

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%22https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for/master/include/macro_sequence_for.h%22%0A%0A%23define+MAKE_FLAGS(name,+seq)+enum+name+%7BSF_FOR_EACH(BODY,+STEP,+FINAL,+0,+seq)%7D%3B%0A%23define+BODY(n,+d,+x)+x+%3D+1+%3C%3C+(d),%0A%23define+STEP(n,+d,+x)+d%2B1%0A%23define+FINAL(n,+d)+_mask+%3D+(1+%3C%3C+(d))+-+1%0A%0AMAKE_FLAGS(E,+(a)(b)(c))%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.22570909891783,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-E+-o+-%27,paneName:Clang,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:Clang,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40234948604993,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:13,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,paneName:%27Clang+output%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Clang+output%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:53.59765051395007,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.77429090108217,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include "macro_sequence_for.h"

#define MAKE_FLAGS(name, seq) enum name {SF_FOR_EACH(BODY, STEP, FINAL, 0, seq)};
#define BODY(n, d, x) x = 1 << (d),
#define STEP(n, d, x) d+1
#define FINAL(n, d) _mask = (1 << (d)) - 1

MAKE_FLAGS(E, (a)(b)(c))
```

This expands to:

```
enum E
{
    a = 1 << (0),                // 0b0001
    b = 1 << (0+1),              // 0b0010
    c = 1 << (0+1+1),            // 0b0100
    _mask = (1 << (0+1+1+1)) - 1 // 0b0111
};
```

If you don't need the combined mask, remove `#define FINAL` and pass `SF_NULL` in its place.

Full disclosure - I'm the library author.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am specifically looking for generating getter functions for clean code

Comment: @Illuminati Why did you mention the enum in the commen then? Changing the code to produce functions instead of enum constants shouldn't be hard. Do you understand how to do that?

Comment: No . That was my original post but someone asked me my usecase and asked me to update it in the post. I would be really grateful if you can please me with that below is what i am trying to achieve constexpr std::array<const char*, 3> arr = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};
    
    //Now at compile time i want to generate functions 
    constexpr int getFoo() { return 0; }
    constexpr int getBar() { return 1; }
    constexpr int getBaz() { return 2; }

Comment: @Illuminati Again, why do you need this? When we asked you this the first time, you replied with a enum - which I understood as *"I don't actually care about the functions, all I want is a enum"*. If it's not that, then what does the enum has to do with it?

Comment: @Illuminati its not clear why you think you need the getters. Getters are not clean code. Clean code is about not writing code that you do not need. Why do you need the getters?